# Lowest possible ratio of number of borders to countries annexable

Tags: mathematics, knowledge, optimization, geography

There's been a recent [trend](https://www.reddit.com/r/mapporncirclejerk/comments/14vmck9/mongolia_if_they_annexed_their_neighbors_and/) on Reddit of finding how many countries can be colored in by:

1. Coloring nation *a*.
2. Coloring *b* nations, those touching *a*'s borders.
3. Coloring *c* nations, those touching *b*'s borders.

Or, in laymen's terms, "size of *a* if they annexed their neighbors and their neighbor's neighbors".

What is the lowest possible ratio of nation's *a*'s *x* border amount to *y* countries annexable?

For example, Costa Rica has two borders, with Nicaragua and Panama. Nicaragua borders El Salvador and Honduras; Panama borders Columbia. That is a total of fives countries annexable. This makes for a ratio of 2/5, or 0.40. The lower this number is, the better.

To avoid ambiguity, only recognized UN member states count as countries.

Bonus For Fun Question: Which country can annex the highest numbers of countries with the smallest number of separation (neighbours)?

Comment: How is the bonus question really different from the main question? The highest total with the fewest neighbours makes for the smallest ratio.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis I see now, my bad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can achieve

> Ratio 1 which is best possible (apologies, I've optimised in the wrong direction; see instead my answer to the bonus question).

with

> Either Haiti or the Dominican Republic who are each other's sole neighbour.

For the bonus question I claim

> Mongolia, which only borders [Russia and China, but is within two hops of 24 countries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_and_territories_by_number_of_land_borders) giving a ratio of 1:12. To beat this a country would either have to have either a single neighbour that is either China or Russia (there is no such country) or share a border only with France and either Russia or China (again there is no such country).

Comment: is it not 25 border countries?

Afghanistan,
Azerbaijan,
Belarus,
Bhutan,
China,  
Estonia, 
Finland, 
Georgia,
India,
Kazakhstan,
Kyrgyzstan, 
Laos,
Latvia,
Lithuania,
Mongolia,
Myanmar,
Nepal,
North Korea,
Norway,
Pakistan,
Poland,
Russia,
Tajikistan,
Ukraine and
Vietnam

Comment: @Topwizard29Thegamer I wasn't counting the start country.

Comment: Ahhhhh right of course, I suppose the question didn't either... my bad!